# SSH passwordless root login gets "Permission denied (publickey)."

Tags: ssh, password, root, key-authentication

I have two Raspberry Pi (with Raspbian 7 and 8) connected to the same LAN. One has a data connection with an APC UPS. There's a couple of similar scripts in both machines to be ran under power failure situations. In `/etc/apcupsd/onbattery` and `/etc/apcupsd/offbattery` (from the UPS attached Pi) I have something similar to:

```
# [...] 
# after the e-mail stuff

# this is for the remote machine
/usr/bin/ssh -f pi@piac-pal_wired "sh -c '/home/pi/bin/my_script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1'"

# this is for the local machine, connected to the UPS
/home/pi/bin/my_script.sh
```

The local script works, but the one for the remote Pi doesn't (error: "Permission denied (publickey)."
It does work if run it as normal user. Again, it doesn't work if run it with `sudo`, from the shell.

So I understand the problem is that the root user can't connect via SSH to the other machine using the shared keys method.

Running the `sudo ssh` command with `-vv` shows that the offered key is the one in `/root/.ssh/id_rsa`. The corresponding public key has been already added to the `root/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote machine and its `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has been configured including:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

If I change the last two lines above in:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitRootLogin yes
```

the root user from the UPS attached Pi can login to the remote Pi, but the command asks for a password, something that can't be accomplished when the apcupsd scripts will run unattended.

Any suggestion is more than welcome. Thanks.

EDIT: adding command output with `ssh -vvv` as suggested.
I think the relevant part is at the end:

```
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '$HOSTNAME' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f8c72a8)
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Check the file/directory permissions of `/root` and `/root/.ssh`. Both should be `drwx------`

Comment: They are. Thanks. (Also `authorized_keys` has mode 600).

Comment: post the sshd logs on the server side?

Comment: in `/var/log/auth.log` I only have `Connection closed by 192.168.xxx.xxx` (the IP of the requesting machine) on every attempt.

Comment: check the /var/log/secure logs to see what they say, also try to ssh to it with ssh -vvv to see where its failing.

Comment: There's no `/var/log/secure` log. Output  with `ssh -vvv` added to the question.   :)

Comment: "The corresponding public key has been already added to the root/.ssh/authorized_keys on the remote machine" - but seems not to be accepted by the remote. Please double check if - it is the correct key and - there is no line break and - `authorized_keys` file is `-rw-------`. Best way to make sure is to allow `root`to login via password, then do `sudo ssh-copy-id <remote>`on the local machine, and afterwards change access back to `PermitRootLogin without-password`.

Comment: Double checked everything you say... Still no joy.

Comment: Wait... Wait... `sudo ssh -i /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa ...` works! Setting explicitly the `pi` user's key works... but why? There's even no need for a `.ssh` dir into server's `/root`...

Comment: Yes, adding the client's root key to the server's `/home/pi/.ssh/authorized_keys` makes the script working also with the initial sintax... So: the /root/.ssh folder is NOT taken into consideration possibly because I was calling via ssh the `pi` user. Must be this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the ssh command was calling the `pi` user, not the `root` one, so, the checked `authorized_keys` was the one in `/home/pi/.ssh`, not the one in `/root/.ssh`. All I needed to do was adding the client's root key to the server's `/home/pi/.ssh/authorized_keys`. That's all.